# What is the scientific term for the photon emission caused by electrons jumping orbitals?

Tags: atomic-physics, terminology

Suppose an electron in an atom at the K-orbital is sufficiently energized (excited) that it jumps to the L-orbital. When this electron returns to its ground electronic state (it jumps back to the K-orbital), in order to respect the law of conservation of energy, the excess energy it has garnered from the excitation is shed through the emission of a photon, the frequency of which varies with the atom. This is why the burning of sodium chloride atop a near-colourless hydrogen flame produces an intense yellow light.

What is the scientific term for this photon emission? I thought it was *Bremsstrahlung*, but turns out that refers to a completely unrelated type of photon emission.

Comment: It's just emission, or maybe 'spontaneous emission' in this case.

Comment: [Spectral emmission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_spectral_series#Physics) also, [quantum leap](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096684/)

Comment: In the case of x-rays, it is called characteristic xray (emission). The emission can be seen in energy spectra as peaks, where bremsstrahlung has a  continous spectrum

Comment: I would call this fluorescence or radiative decay.

Answer (score 0):

Excitation of electrons to higher orbitals  give spectral absorption lines. The consequent deexcitations give spectral [emission lines.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_line)

[image: spectra]

The term is spectral lines, to contrast with the continuum produced by other emissions.